# How old is Squidward in Spongebob Squarepants?

Tags: character, spongebob-squarepants

So we know Spongebob is older than 16 since he drives, but Squidward
here has an mystery age.

He has a full time job just like Spongebob but he has driving skills better than Spongebob.

So he has to be 17-18. He's always been said to be "mature" based on the first episode.

He live alone like Spongebob, so he would have to be at least 18 but I'm guessing. Laws are different underwater.

Comment: why do you assume that the driving age in BB is 16?

Answer (score 2):

According to this Wiki, he's 42:http://spongefan.wikia.com/wiki/Squidward_Q._Tentacles 
But then it also says he dies last February so not sure.. Most sites point to 40s

Answer (score 1):

According to [this wikia](http://spongebob.wikia.com/wiki/SpongeBob_SquarePants_%28character%29) Spongebob Square pants was born in 1986 (July 14, which means he is now 30... and a week younger than me...)

While Squidward was born in 1972, so he is 44, according to [this site](http://spongefan.wikia.com/wiki/Squidward_Q._Tentacles).